# Maven artifact jar different name than version

Tags: java, maven

I got a small question about Maven. I got a project my pom.xml

It has basically this repositories:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>alfresco-mirror</id>
        <name>Alfresco Public Mirror</name> 
        <url>http://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>alfresco-snapshots</id>
        <name>Alfresco Public Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>    
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>alfresco</id>
        <name>Alfresco Public </name>
        <url>http://pipin.bluexml.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>    
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and this dependency:

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco-web-service-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.d</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>
```

I think the main problem is that jar file and version got different names.
How can I solve this?

I thank your help in advance.

PS: Just for save time, [this dependency link location](http://pipin.bluexml.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/alfresco/alfresco-web-service-client/3.4.d/)

Comment: Errr... what *exactly* is your main problem? Can't resolve a dependency?

Comment: Yes, it tries to find depency alfresco-web-service-client-3.4.d.jar(but the name in the repository is alfresco-web-service-client-3.4.d-community.jar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding a classifier node to see if that works:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
    <artifactId>alfresco-web-service-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.d</version>
    <classifier>community</classifier>
    <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>  
</dependencies>
```

You can see the reasoning behind that [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html). Long story short, classifiers are just appended to that artifact name right after the version number. They're not used all that often, but you do see them from time to time.