# How to define dependency while JAR name doesn't have version?

Tags: maven, repository, pom.xml

I have a library `AXMLPrinter2.jar` located at `generic-local/corey/AXMLPrinter2/1.0/` on my private maven repository, here is the pom file:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>corey</groupId>
  <artifactId>AXMLPrinter2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

When I tried to add it as a dependency in my project:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>corey</groupId>
  <artifactId>AXMLPrinter2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It will cause an error like this:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project: The following artifacts
>   could not be resolved: corey:AXMLPrinter2:jar:1.0 Could not find
>   artifact corey:AXMLPrinter2:jar:1.0 in central
>   (http://myip:8081/artifactory/generic-local)

From the log, it tried to find **AXMLPrinter2-1.0.jar**, but the library's name is **AXMLPrinter2.jar** (without -1.0) actually, how can I solve this issue?
I found some similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278327/how-to-install-dependency-when-jar-name-differs-from-folder-version-name) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279447/maven-artifact-jar-different-name-than-version), but didn't work.

**How to include a dependency and specify its real name in pom file?**

Comment: How did it get into the maven repository in the first place? Did you copy it by hand? If you want to read it from a Maven repository it has to have the right name, i.e. including the version number.

Comment: I got it from my co-worker, and I put it into our own maven repo, I don't know how to deal with this problem (a library without version number), any idea?

Comment: Seems the only thing I can do is rename the library name to `xxx-1.0.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

checkout the version of the jar in the META-INF folder and inject it in the pom file.

Comment: In the META-INF folder, it has a file `MANIFEST.MF`, it shows `Manifest-Version: 1.0 Main-Class: test.AXMLPrinter`, how to inject into my pom file? any example?

Comment: Its version is 1.0 and you added dependency correctly. I think the problem might at linking of jar and maven. Please check and try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I want to pull the jar from my own maven repo, I don't want to put it in my source control.